# How to center Title but have Nav all the way to the right with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox and have the `h1` and `nav` on the same line so i have `display:flex` with the default direction of row. I want title to be centered and the nav to the right. I was wondering if theres a way to move the navigation all the way to the right. I have tried `margin-right:auto` on the `h1` and tried to find a property like `align-self` for the main axis when its set to row but I cant figure it out. I had `justify-content:center` originally but gave up and set it back to `space-between`.

```js
   import React from 'react';
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
   
   const Header = () => {
     return (
       <header className='header--container'>
         <Link to='/'>
           <h1 className='header--title'>Cocktail Connaisseur</h1>
         </Link>
         <Link to='/cocktails/a'>
           <nav className='header--nav'>
             <p>All Cocktails</p>
           </nav>
         </Link>
       </header>
     );
   };
   
   export default Header;
```

---

index.css

```css
/*Header Styling */

.header--container {
  background-color: #55505c;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header--container>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header--title {
  margin: 0;
  color: #e8e9f3;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header--nav {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.header--nav>p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #e8e9f3;
}
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would help a lot and would greatly increase your chances of having a good response. You can read about how to create it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It also isn't clear if you want to centre the title (and by title I assume you mean "the main heading" and not `<title>`) in the space remaining after the navbar is accounted for or in the centre of the browser window regardless of the navbar. (I'd assume the former normally).

Comment: you have to move entire container on the right side, but you really have to add a minimal reproducible example here

Comment: just fixed everything, sorry i thought it would be a quick answer that someone could help me with

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more container on top then your output will work perfectly as per your requirement.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className='header--container'>
      <div/>
      <Link to='/'>
        <h1 className='header--title'>Cocktail Connaisseur</h1>
      </Link>
      <Link to='/cocktails/a'>
        <nav className='header--nav'>
          <p>All Cocktails</p>
        </nav>
      </Link>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

add flex:1; to the   .header--title and i removed the justify from the container

```css
/*Header Styling */
.header--container {
  background-color: #55505c;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  
}

.header--container > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header--title {
flex:1 ;
  margin: 0;
  color: #e8e9f3;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.header--nav {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.header--nav > p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #e8e9f3;
}
```

```html
<header class='header--container'>
      <Link to='/'>
        <h1 class='header--title'>Cocktail Connaisseur</h1>
      </Link>
      <Link to='/cocktails/a'>
        <nav class='header--nav'>
          <p>All Cocktails</p>
        </nav>
      </Link>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a div and place the title into the div:

```js
<div class="header--title">
  <Link href="/">
    <h1>Cocktail Connaisseur</h1>
  </Link>
</div>
```

then in the css:

```css
.header--title {
  width: 80%; //You can modify this and see the exact amount due to responsive stuff.
  color: #e8e9f3;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10%;// 100% - width / 2
}
```

and it'll place your title exactly in the center and your nav links on the right.